# How to detect that user is leaving or opening homescreen in Android

Tags: java, android

In my application i need to show on overlay view **only on home screen**. At this moment my overlay view is shown not only on home screen but also on top of any launched activity. Are there any ways of detecting that user is leaving or opening home screen?

My application is developed in the next way:
I have a Service where i am creating a view and adding it to WindowManager with this flag WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT. And i am also have this permission in AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

  }

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

  }

@Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

  }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I have no running Activities in my application. I have a service, where i am creating view and adding it to WindowManager. And i need to show this view only on home screen but not over any running activity in Android.

Comment: make a global variable and change the value in activity states  this let you to decide by comparing it in service.